# Scrolling with fixed header on resizable table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to add a scroll on my resizable table with fixed headers and I managed halfway through. Indeed, I follow a [tutorial](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/making-resizable-table-js.html) to have a resizable table and it work properly. Then I wanted to have a scroll bar and I found a tutorial as well but it does not really work. I found many subjects on stackoverflow but I did not succeed to make it work.

I tried to add this in the style but does not work:

```
tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Indeed, the thead and tbody are not aligned anymore. 
If I change the display it fits but I don't have the scroll anymore. What can I do ?

Here is my snippet:

```js
const resizableGrid = (table) => {
  const row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
  const cols = row ? row.children : undefined;

  if (cols === undefined) return;

  for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.height = table.offsetHeight + 'px';
    div.className = 'columnSelector';
    cols[i].appendChild(div);
    cols[i].style.position = 'relative';
    setListeners(div);
  }
}

const setListeners = (div) => {
  let pageX, curCol, nxtCol, curColWidth, nxtColWidth;
  div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    curCol = e.target.parentElement;
    nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
    pageX = e.pageX;
    curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth;
    if (nxtCol) {
      nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth;
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (curCol) {
      const diffX = e.pageX - pageX;
      if (nxtCol) {
        nxtCol.style.width = (nxtColWidth - (diffX)) + 'px';
      }
      curCol.style.width = (curColWidth + diffX) + 'px';
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    curCol = undefined;
    nxtCol = undefined;
    pageX = undefined;
    nxtColWidth = undefined;
    curColWidth = undefined;
  });
}

const table = document.getElementById('tableExample');
resizableGrid(table);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 31px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.col1 {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.col6 {
  display: none;
}

thead {
  background-color: DarkSlateGray;
}

.columnSelector {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.columnSelector:hover {
  border-right: 2px solid green;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableExample">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">COL1</th>
      <th>COL2</th>
      <th>COL3</th>
      <th>COL4</th>
      <th>COL5</th>
      <th class="col6">COL6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td>ITEM</td>
      <td class="col6">ITEM</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you're saying you want another scrollbar on the table itself?

Comment: Yes, I want a scrollbar in the table itself but without changing everything I have done before with the resizable column @Keith

Comment: Well the problem is your tbody tag is set just for column one, so adding a scroll element doesn't make sense since you can't scroll. Is the idea column 1 will be a set height and scrolled on its own while the other columns can be filled past the set height of column 1?

Comment: Nope the height will be the same for all the columns. But I am not setting the tbody tag just for column one, where do you see that ? @Keith